# pycharm no module named redis

Tags: python, redis, pycharm

I installed python，Django and Redis. In Vim I use “import redis” is OK， when I use pycharm IDE to code， I write “import redis” ， the pycharm tip “no module named redis”， why？ what should I to do ？

Comment: Have you setup python interpreter for the project?

Comment: @JavaFreshman, did you install this package https://pypi.python.org/pypi/redis? Is "In Vim I use “import redis” is OK" means that there is no `ImportError` when you start this script?

Comment: @DenisNikanorov I install the package, in vim I start the script it's all right, but i copy the same code in pycharm , the IDE tips 'no module named redis'

Answer (score 9):

As per my understanding pycharm will say "No module named redis" if you haven't set up python interpreter in pycharm or in case there is no such module you are trying to use installed in the python interpreter you are currently using for pycharm.

To add python interpreter to pycharm go to 
File -> Settings -> Python interpreter

[image]

Comment: I installed pip, all is OK now !! thank you , but I still don't know why?

Answer (score 5):

Ansuman's tip got me part way there, but `import redis` was still going red. I had an interpreter selected, but it turned out I did not have `pip` installed, nor did I have the `redis` package installed.

To get those, go to `File > Settings > Python Interpreter` (or `PyCharm > Preferences > Python Interpreter` on Mac) and select `Configure Interpreters`. At the bottom it will suggest to install `pip` (sorry, no screenshot). Do this. After `pip` is installed, install the `redis` module by selecting `Install`.

In the new window, search on `redis`. Select `redis` (you may have to scroll down, it didn't appear at the top for me), then select `Install Package`.

[image: Installing redis from available packages on PyCharm]

Obviously, this should work for all packages, not just `redis`.

Comment: Hello I had similar issue, initially I did't have pip installed and I manually installed it from terminal. But pycharm still shows pip is not

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple.
Rename your program file from "redis.py" to other name. (cf. redis_test.py etc).